# ImportError: No module named Tkinter

Tags: python, tensorflow, rhel

My object_detection code is running perfectly on Jupyter Notebook. However, when i execute it after converting to .py file. Following error is throwing.

> ```
> [root@linux object_detection]# python object_detection_tutorial.py
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):  
> File "object_detection_tutorial.py", line 22, in <module>
>     from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
>   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
>     _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
>   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 62, in pylab_setup
>     [backend_name], 0)
>   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 4, in <module>
>     from . import tkagg  # Paint image to Tk photo blitter extension.
>   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/tkagg.py", line 5, in <module>
>     from six.moves import tkinter as Tk
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 203, in load_module
>     mod = mod._resolve()
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
>     return _import_module(self.mod)
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
>     __import__(name)
> ImportError: No module named Tkinter
> ```

Python Version: 2.7

Linux : RHEL

Comment: `pip install tkinter` ?

Comment: 'How to install Tkinter module with python 2.7.5 in Redhat linux 7?' is not working on my system neither 'pip install tkinter'

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your question. The stack trace is very difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

I installed tkinter package on my server and it resolved this issue.

Comment: Please note that my python version is python-2.7.5-34.el7.x86_64. Tkinter  package(tkinter-2.7.5-34.el7.x86_64.rpm) must match according to python package